# Hyper-degree sequences: How to count them and how to construct hyper-graphs from them?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, hypergraph

From an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3788911/1792) to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788654/reconstructing-sets-of-sets-from-reduced-membership-information) I have learned how to ask this question properly.

Consider a [$k$-uniform hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) on $n$ nodes, i.e. a family of $k$-subsets of $[n]= \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ (the hyperedges).

Consider a sequence $\langle a_1, a_2, \dots a_n \rangle$ giving the numbers of hyperedges that node $i\in [n]$ is contained in. In the case of $k=2$ this is the classical degree sequence. So let me call the sequence a **[hyper-degree sequence](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22hyper-degree%20sequence%22)** when $k\leq n$ is arbitrary.

It obviously holds that $a_i \leq \binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

For $k=2$ we know by the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)  that $\sum_i a_i  = 0 \text{ mod } 2$, and I assume that this holds for all $k$: $\sum_i a_i  = 0 \text{ mod } k$.

My question is fourfold:

- What's the best known algorithm (probably not "efficient") to check if a given sequence $\langle a_1, a_2, \dots a_n \rangle$ with $a_i \leq \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and $\sum_i a_i  = 0 \text{ mod } k$ is the hyper-degree sequence of some $k$-uniform hypergraph on $n$ nodes?
- Even though it may be hard to tell exactly how many of such sequences are hyper-degree sequences, there may be a definite fraction for $n \rightarrow \infty$. How could this fraction be calculated?
- Before delving into this: Are there further simple necessary conditions for a sequence to be a hyper-degree sequence? For example, for $k=2$ there must be at least $\alpha$ nodes $i \neq 1$ with $a_i \geq 1$ when  $a_1 = \alpha$.
- Finally: How do I construct a $k$-uniform hypergraph for a given hyper-degree sequence?

Comment: For counting them do you want your degree sequences sorted nonincreasing? It seems now the degree sequence of $\{12, 23\}$ would be $(1,2,1)$ as defined in the question.

Comment: @JohnMachacek: You are right, I should have been explicit about sorting, and yes, I want my degree sequences sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Dewdney generalized the Havel--Hakimi algorithm for standard graph degree sequences to hypergraphs in 1975: Degree seqences in complexes and hypergraphs, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 53, 535-540.

You might also look at Sarah Behrens et al., New results of degree sequences of uniform hypergraphs, *Electron. J. Combin.* 20 (2013) P14.

Comment: How do you propose turning Dewdney's result into an algorithm without a brute-force search for $(k-1)$-graphic sequences that satisfy the theorem?

Comment: This paper seems relevant [https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03951](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03951)